# Number of elements in a finitely generated Dynkin system

Tags: combinatorics, measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

How can I show that the [Dynkin system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynkin_system) generated by $n$ subsets of a set has at most $2^{n+1}$ elements?

It's easy to show for pairwise disjoint subsets and intuitively I feel like that's when the cardinality is maximal, but I haven't found a proof yet.

I've tried showing it inductively by considering the following sets:

- the Dynkin system generated by n given subsets, let's call it $D_{n}$,
- for a given $(n+1)$st subset $A_{n+1}$, the set of all disjoint unions of it with elements of $D_{n}$: $\{A_{n+1} \cup B \vert B \in D_{n}, A_{n+1} \cap B = \emptyset \}$,
- the set of all complements of those sets:  $\{(A_{n+1} \cup B)^{c} \vert B \in D_{n}, A_{n+1} \cap B = \emptyset \}$.

If I could show that the union of those three sets is a Dynkin system the proof would be done, because by induction hypothesis $D_{n}$ has at most $2^{n+1}$ elements and the other two sets have at most $2^{n}$ elements each, which would be $2^{n+2}$ at most in total. The problem is that I can't show closedness under disjoint unions, could anyone help me with that?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

If you are not only interested in a proof by induction,you could try to show that  $D(\mathcal{J})$ cardinality is lower than $\#P(n+1)$ for $\#\mathcal{J}=n$ ,to do so you can  WLOG assume that $\mathcal{J} $ is linearly ordered set by $ \subseteq $
,then you can prove that $$ \#P((\Omega )\cup \mathcal{J})\geq\#D(\mathcal{J})$$ 
since there is a 
surjective function $$f:P((\Omega )\cup \mathcal{J})\ \rightarrow D(\mathcal{J})$$
$f(\{A_k,...,A_j\})=A_j\backslash ....\backslash A_k$

Comment: Why can I assume WLOG that $\mathcal{J}$ is linearly ordered by $\subseteq$? I mean, how to I then show it when it isn't linearly ordered?

Also I don't understand your last sentence.

Comment: If  it is not then, you dont have to take all $A_j\backslash...\backslash A_k  $ since  if $A_j \nsubseteq  A_k $ and $ A_k \nsubseteq A_j$ then  $A_j \backslash A_k \notin D(\mathcal{J})$
and then $\#D(\mathcal{J}) <\# P((\Omega)\cup \mathcal{J})$

Comment: Every element of $ D(\mathcal{J}) $could be expressed in form $A_j\backslash ....\backslash A_k$ where $A_j,...,A_k \in (\Omega)\cup \mathcal{J}$